# How to make network call and update UI in Windows 8 C# metro app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In my WP7 app I use HttpWebRequest class to make http call to webservice and load the data. From UI thread I make the network call by using Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method, once I have received response I use the same Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke  method to update the UI. How do we do the same thing in Windows 8 C# metro app or what is the equivalent method in windows 8 metro app?. Can we use same HttpWebRequest class or some other class we need to use for making network call. Please clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.jayway.com/2012/04/12/converting-to-windows-8-from-windows-phone-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest-5-of-12/) blog post has all the details for this issue. This is from a series on converting WP7 apps to Windows 8.

You need to use the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Also you no longer need the Dispatcher invokes. You can just use `async` and `await` and everything works on the same calling thread.

Comment: When you use `async` in this scenario, all of your code *is* single-threaded.

Comment: Agreed. In this scenario everything is single threaded. Edited post.